# Cant write to public folder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to manage my fileuploading but it seems I cant write to the folder `public/uploads`.
I have write permission so I'm not sure what it can be, does somebody see a typo?

**I use the intervention/image library.**

My code is:

```
$file = Input::file($fileName);

if ($file->isValid()) {
    if ($file->getMimeType() == 'image/jpeg' || $file->getMimeType() == 'image/png') {
        $path = public_path("uploads", $file->getClientOriginalName());
        Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(180, null)->save($path);
    } else {
        throw new FileException;
    }
}
```

The exception thrown is:

`Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotWritableException`

`Can't write image data to path (/home/vagrant/Sites/cms/public/uploads)`

Comment: What is the error you get? This code seems correct.

Comment: @GézaTörök I've editted my question with the exception info.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the typo...

I had:
`$path = public_path("uploads", $file->getClientOriginalName());`

Changed to: 
`$path = public_path("uploads/" . $file->getClientOriginalName());`

Thanks for the quick answer though!

Comment: Mark your own answer as correct, so that other users who come across it can see the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the permissions of the folder, and its parent folders. If you're on linux, it should be 644. The individual folder may have write access, but the parent might not; or it could be for the wrong user. Check the Ownership group too.

Comment: I have the permissions. My .js and .css files are in the public folder as well. Those are loaded correctly.